# Equation for non linear data

Tags: math, image-processing, prediction

I have a set of non linear data. The data is the X & Y coordinates of different objects/points in a video( that is the x&y pixel co-ordinates of same objects in all the frames in a video.) upon plotting the values in one frame, I am getting a nonlinear graph as shown in the picture.

[image]

I want to form an equation for this graph so that, if I have a known X coorrdinate in this frame, then the corresponding Y coordinate can be obtained using this equation.(kind of predicting the new position, I am not sure this idea is correct or not)

OR

If this idea is illogical, can you suggest something that will work so that I can predict the location of new object using these data.

Any help or new ideas is highly appreciated.

A sample of my data is given below:

```
X            Y


----------


214         182
830         185
1451        173
219         554
1453        548
214         941
830         934
1455        942
213         190
829         193
1450        181
218         561
1452        555
214         945
830         938
1455        946
213         190
828         193
1451        182
219         560
1452        554
214         945
830         938
1455        946
213         190
829         193
1450        181
219         556
1453        550
215         936
830         929
1455        937
```

I have selected 9 objects in each frame, so the first 9 data set belongs to one frame, and so on..

Comment: If you are developing about a single person or object and you expect same behavior every time in later experiments, you may improve your data quality using  `genetic algorithm` to predict using more than 9 point.

Comment: If you want to process data only a single time using this data, first you have to predict what kind of curve should fit to data. e.g. If data should fit a conic chart, you should not rely on a linear equation. First decide if your data is Linear, Polynomial, Conic or even a French curve

Comment: The data is not linear. If i plot the points, i will be getting a rectangle since i have selected the points in such a way(rectangle shape).

Comment: Rectangle is not presenting a logical function (You can not predict value on vertical parts of chart). So why the sample chart seems not to be linear?

Comment: These data look a bit chaotic. But they seem to form eight clusters. Can you describe what the data represent? Without prior knowledge, it will be virtually impossible to fit anything reasonable.

Comment: You need a scatter plot (XY-plot) and not a line plot. The line plot does not use the _values_ of the _x_-axis, but rather treats them as categories.

Comment: @NicoSchertler these 8 points are 8 markers on a frame which are placed at the otline of an image. based on how these markers move in the successive frames, I want to determine the coordinates of other objects in this frame. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems you might want to fit a homography to these markers. Then, you can transform any point with the homography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *XY* data looks like this:

[image: XY]

There are clusters located on corners and mid-edges.

and when the lines that connect successive points are added

[image: XY2]

The points should come in groups of 8, in the sequence shown above. You can predict the location of a point using the index

```
// predict location `(x,y)` of point based on index `i`
point = MOD(i-1,8)+1;  // get number 1-8 of the point (as shown above)
select case point
    case [1,4,6] : x = 215;
    case [2,7] : x = 829;
    case [3,5,8] : x = 1463;
end select
select case point
    case [1,2,3] : y = 186;
    case [4,5] : y = 555;
    case [6,7,8] : y = 940;
end select
```

Comment: Yeah, when I plot theses points it will look like this. My question is, If i want to find the coordinates of a point inside this rectangle, how can I do it?

Comment: So you want to know the bounds of for the x and y values. Something like `200<x<1450` ? Because an interior point is going to be within those bounds.

Comment: Thanks for tryinng this out for me @ja72 . Just the boundary values are not enough for me. I want the cordinate, if I input an x value to the equation I obtain from the above figure, I should get its corresponding y value. But I think, that is not possible with this 8 boundary values. I am going for plotting the delta values between the cordinates, which might help.

Comment: @mira - the curve is not a function where one value of x corresponds to a single value of y. There is no way to do what you are asking mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut this curve in lot of linear lines, so following the value of X, you will be on linear line and its easy to calculate the equation of line knowing 2 points of this line